# Getting user data with Laravel Sanctum

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-passport, laravel-sanctum

I was using Laravel's built-in api token authentication before but I wanted to provide multiple api tokens for different clients and with Laravel 7.x, I'm trying to migrate to Laravel Sanctum.

API seems authenticates user without any problem but when I try to get user data with `Auth::user();`, it returns null. Also  `Auth::guard('api')->user();` returns null too.

What should I use as Auth guard? Or is it correct way to get user data based on provided token?

Thank you very much....

Comment: Was a custom middleware used for the authentication? If you did and the problem is not resolved, can post the contents of the middleware?

Comment: Use either `@parsa-samandizadeh` solution, or use an optional sanctum auth middleware as described in: https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/laravel-sanctum-optional-auth-on-route?page=1&replyId=680807

Comment: Did you put "Bearer " before token string to header.Authorization field on Request.

Answer (score 42):

`auth('sanctum')->user()->id`

`auth('sanctum')->check()`

---

without middleware, you could use these.

Comment: Should be the top answer, exactly what was needed, thanks!

Answer (score 28):

First, route through the sanctum auth middleware.

```php
Route::get('/somepage', 'SomeController@MyMethod')->middleware('auth:sanctum');
```

Then, get the user.

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class AuthController extends Controller
{
    public function MyMethod(Request $request) {
        return $request->user();
    }
}
```

`auth()->user()` is a global helper, `Auth::user()` is a support facade, and `$request->user()` uses http. You can use any of them.
For a quick test, try

```php
Route::get('/test', function() {
    return auth()->user();
})->middleware('auth:sanctum');
```

Be sure to send your token in a header like so:

```
Authorization: Bearer UserTokenHere
```

Comment: unforturnately for API requests, $request->user() and auth()->user() returns null. Auth::user() returns null as well (seems requires guard provided)

Comment: @shehatesme Did you send the token in a header with the request like above?

Comment: @shehatesme You need to use the `auth:sanctum` middleware otherwise it will return null

Answer (score 3):

[image: Authorization header]

Send token in the Authorization header, below code return the auth user.

```
Route::middleware('auth:sanctum')->group(function () {
    Route::get('/profile/me', function (Request $request) {
        return $request->user();
    });
});
```

In case of restful api, suggest you to send **Accept** header also for checking at authenticate middleware for redirection if not authenticated. By default for restful api it redirect to login form (if any) if user not authenticated.

```
namespace App\Http\Middleware;

protected function redirectTo($request)
{
    if (!$request->expectsJson()) {
        return route('login');
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't have any problem about redirection, I just need to get Auth::user() data in controller.

Comment: @shehatesme Try with Auth::guard('sanctum')->user()

Answer (score 3):

The simplest way to to that is to use `auth` helpers like

```
$user =  auth('sanctum')->user();
```

Or you can get it by the request object

```
//SomeController.php
public function exampleMethod(Request $request)
{
   $user = $request->user();
}
```

To get user by sactum token string like

```
2|bTNlKViqCkCsOJOXWbtNASDKF7SyHwzHOPLNH
```

Code be like

```
use Laravel\Sanctum\PersonalAccessToken;
//...
$token = PersonalAccessToken::findToken($sactumToken);
$user = $token->tokenable;
```

**Note:** The most way to pass token is from Authorization headers by bearer

Answer (score 1):

When you are logging in the user, in your login function use something like this

```
public function login(Request $request)
{
    if(Auth::attempt($credentials))
    {
         $userid = auth()->user()->id;
    }
}
```

Then send this user id to the client and let it store in a secured way on client-side. Then with every request, you can use this user-id to serve data for next requests.

Answer (score 0):

```
 private $status_code= 200; // successfully

    public function register(Request $request)
    {
        // $validator = $this->validator($request->all())->validate();
        $validator = Validator::make($request->all(),
            [
                'name' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
                'email' => ['required', 'string', 'email', 'max:255'], // , 'unique:users'
                'password' => ['required', 'string', 'min:4'],
            ]
        );
        if($validator->fails()) {
            return response()->json(["status" => "failed", "message" => "Please Input Valid Data", "errors" => $validator->errors()]);
        }
        $user_status = User::where("email", $request->email)->first();
        if(!is_null($user_status)) {
           return response()->json(["status" => "failed", "success" => false, "message" => "Whoops! email already registered"]);
        }

        $user = $this->create($request->all());
        if(!is_null($user)) {
            $this->guard()->login($user);
            return response()->json(["status" => $this->status_code, "success" => true, "message" => "Registration completed successfully", "data" => $user]);
        }else {
            return response()->json(["status" => "failed", "success" => false, "message" => "Failed to register"]);
        }
    }
    /**
     * Get a validator for an incoming registration request.
     *
     * @param  array  $data
     * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Validator
     */
    protected function validator(array $data)
    {
        return Validator::make($data, [
            'name' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
            'email' => ['required', 'string', 'email', 'max:255', 'unique:users'],
            'password' => ['required', 'string', 'min:4'],
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * Create a new user instance after a valid registration.
     * @author Mohammad Ali Abdullah .. 
     * @param  array  $data
     * @return \App\User
     */
    protected function create(array $data)
    {
        return User::create([
            'name' => $data['name'],
            'email' => $data['email'],
            'password' => Hash::make($data['password']),
        ]);
    }
    protected function guard()
    {
        return Auth::guard();
    }
    /**
     * method public
    * @author Mohammad Ali Abdullah
    * @date 01-01-2021.
    */
    public function login(Request $request)
    {

        $validator = Validator::make($request->all(),
            [
                "email"             =>          "required|email",
                "password"          =>          "required"
            ]
        );
        // check validation email and password .. 
        if($validator->fails()) {
            return response()->json(["status" => "failed", "validation_error" => $validator->errors()]);
        }
        // check user email validation ..
        $email_status = User::where("email", $request->email)->first();
        if(!is_null($email_status)) {
            // check user password validation ..
            // ---- first try -----
            // $password_status    =   User::where("email", $request->email)->where("password", Hash::check($request->password))->first();
            // if password is correct ..
            // ---- first try -----
            // if(!is_null($password_status)) {
            if(Hash::check($request->password, $email_status->password)) {
                $credentials = $request->only('email', 'password');
                if (Auth::attempt($credentials)) {
                    // Authentication passed ..
                    $authuser = auth()->user();
                    return response()->json(["status" => $this->status_code, "success" => true, "message" => "You have logged in successfully", "data" => $authuser]);
                }
            }else {
                return response()->json(["status" => "failed", "success" => false, "message" => "Unable to login. Incorrect password."]);
            }
        }else{
            return response()->json(["status" => "failed", "success" => false, "message" => "Email doesnt exist."]);
        }
    }

    public function logout()
    {
        Auth::logout();
        return response()->json(['message' => 'Logged Out'], 200);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I see that no answer has been accepted yet. I just had the problem that my sacntum auth did not work. The auth() helper always returned null.

To solve the problem I removed the comment in the kernel.php under the api key. It is about this class `\Laravel\Sanctum\Http\Middleware\EnsureFrontendRequestsAreStateful::class`. This is because it is commented out by default.

```php
'api' => [
    \Laravel\Sanctum\Http\Middleware\EnsureFrontendRequestsAreStateful::class,
    'throttle:api',
    \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
],
```

After that I had access to the User object with the auth() helper.

Answer (score 0):

I use the controller's __constructor() function to set a protected variable and could then access the user object throughout the controller.

```
/**
 * Authenticated user object
 *
 * @var \Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable|null
 */
protected $user;

/**
 * Create a new controller instance.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware(function ($request, $next) {
        $this->user = Auth::user();
        return $next($request);
    });
}
```

Works like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use `auth()` method to get user information inside api routes as well.
You can use it like this.

```
auth()->user()->name
```

To check whether it is working you can `info(auth()->user()->name)` inside your route function and it will print the user's data on laravel.log. The path of this file is `/storage/logs/laravel.log`

Answer (score -1):

Make sure the sanctum middleware is in api

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -2):

I was in the same boat; migrated to Sanctum and wondered why all of my $request->user() were empty.  The solution for me was to throw some middleware onto the stack to modify the request's user() resolver:

```
namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class PromoteSanctumUser
{
    /**
     * @param Request $request
     * @param \Closure $next
     */
    public function handle(Request $request, \Closure $next)
    {
        $sanctumUser = auth('sanctum')->user();

        if ($sanctumUser) {
            $request->setUserResolver(function() use ($sanctumUser) {
                return $sanctumUser;
            });
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```